# Migration from HTTPAsyncClient to HTTPClient5 - Replacement for PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager? and how to set Socket timeout on RequestConfig?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpasyncclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am migrating from HTTPAsyncCLient to HTTPCLient5 to make use of the HTTP/2 support that comes with it.

We used to use PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager as our connection manager but it is no longer available. I was wondering what the best replacement for it is and why? is PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager the right candidate for it?

Also, the API to set the socket connection timeout is no longer available. What is the alternative for it now?

Previously:
RequestConfig.Builder builder =RequestConfig.custom()
.setSocketTimeout(something)

I am new to this and most likely have some knowledge gaps. It would be great if someone can help me out or point me to a resource to understand it.

Comment: Please take a look at https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/migration-guide/index.html